# Creating DB2 table in SAS adds missing values

Tags: db2, odbc, sas

I ran into this problem when I tried to upload a list of members to our DB2 server, and have created a minimal example to explain the problem.

In order to join locally-created data tables from SAS 9.2 to tables in our DB2 data warehouse (accessed with a connection to an ODBC driver), my procedure has been to place those local tables on the same server (different schema) that houses the claims. The primary purpose of this is to filter out a list of claims where the member_ID is contained in the uploaded list.

If there are missing values in the first row of the local data (sometimes a member might not have a piece of identifying information), the data on the local side loses several non-missing values when it gets uploaded to the DB2 schema. I've attached a toy example with non-sensitive information to highlight the problem.

```
PROC IMPORT OUT= WORK.druglist DATAFILE= "C:\Users\caden2\Desktop\druglist.xls" 
DBMS=EXCEL REPLACE; 
RANGE="'Tab 4# Asthma Meds$'"; 
RUN;

DATA for_clinical;
SET druglist(KEEP= Drug_Class Drug_Type Generic GPI);
IF _N_ = 4 THEN DELETE;
IF _N_ <= 10;
IF _N_ = 1 THEN DO;
    Drug_Class=''; 
    Drug_Type='';
    Generic='';
    END;
RUN;

libname clinic odbc user=XXX password=XXX dsn=DWName schema=DWSchema autocommit=yes;

PROC SQL;
DROP TABLE clinic.caden_test;
CREATE TABLE clinic.caden_test AS
    SELECT * FROM for_clinical;
QUIT;
```

The PROC IMPORT and Data step are simply to get the data into the form I need, and should not have any issues. The clinical library is created through an ODBC connection to our data warehouse with my credentials. The screenshot below shows a before and after of the data set on the local machine and the clinical server (notice the first row has some missingness). I didn't post the log. What is scary is that my log provided no indication that anything was wrong.

[image]

Is this a problem with DB2, SAS, or a combination of SAS and DB2? I am not able to replicate the problem going from local-to-local or DB2-to-DB2. Additionally, the removed values always appear in a diagonal formation. With wider data (more than 4 variables), it starts at a random row and proceeds diagonally up and to the right until it reaches the last column.

To address BellevueBob's concern in the comments that it is not Viewtable messing up, here is the output of a PROC FREQ on the clinical data, showing that the missingness is indeed there. [image]

BellevueBob's answer works for the case when the missing data is character, but creating a data table in the same fashion, but with numeric data, the solution does not work like how it does with character data.

Comment: I wasn't sure whether this was a bug with SAS, DB2, or PEBKAC, so I tagged the first two.

Comment: Can you modify your question to add the complete SAS `libname` statement used for `clinic`?  Also, are you sure the DB2 table itself has the incorrect column values?  `viewtable` is notoriously picky.

Comment: I've updated the description to highlight your concerns. I've censored out my username, password, dsn and schema, but the statement is a pretty vanilla ODBC declaration. The SQL call doesn't give any indication that "clinic" is a remote library or a local one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not generally a fan of answering my own question, but I figured this might be something someone could stumble upon.

I contacted SAS Technical Support with wording almost identical to this question, and this was their response:

> This looks like the driver buffering issue documented in the following
>   SAS Note:
>
> http://support.sas.com/kb/38/214.html
>
> If insertbuff fixes it then you may want to see about getting the IBM
>   Db2 ODBC driver instead.   Let me know if this is not the issue.

To my original example, the solution is as simple as adding an additional option to the original libname statement. Instead of

```
libname clinic odbc user=XXX password=XXX dsn=DWName schema=DWSchema autocommit=yes;
```

The new statement would be

```
libname clinic odbc user=XXX password=XXX dsn=DWName schema=DWSchema insertbuff=1 autocommit=yes;
```

This fix works for both numeric and character data. It is luckily such a corner-case problem that it seems like it only applies to DB2.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `NULLCHAR=NO` data set option:

```
PROC SQL;
   DROP TABLE clinic.caden_test;
   CREATE TABLE clinic.caden_test(NULLCHAR=NO) AS
   SELECT * FROM for_clinical3;
QUIT;
```

Here is **[a SAS reference](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acreldb/63647/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001371592.htm)**.

I have not used DB2 in quite a while and don't know how tables are created through ODBC.  However, I'd also investigate the other available data set options, in particular `DBCREATE_TABLE_OPTS` and `DBTYPE`, which let you explicitly define the table index and column types.

**EDIT:** Corrected answer based on OP comments.

The `NULLCHAR=NO` option tells SAS to send a single-blank character to the database when inserting missing values rather than setting the value to a NULL.  Although this works, it is probably worthy of a SAS usage note.

Comment: I might need to open this up again, but your solution works on my toy data set. I'm going to try running it on a much larger, much more real data set and see if the issue persists. As a note, NULLCHAR=YES did not fix the problem. Switching YES to NO, however, did fix the problem. Do you have a decent explanation for why telling DB2 that a SAS null char should be treated as val would cause the deletion in non-empty fields to go away? Your solution is indistinguishable from magic to me ;).

Comment: I'm only guessing, but I bet it has to do with the DB2 column data types used when the table is created and perhaps if they have the `NOT NULL` attribute.  Oftentimes, if you fail to specify a table index, the first column is used and possibly set to `NOT NULL` by default.  SAS uses a single-quote as a character "missing value" (not having a concept of NULL), so using NULLCHAR=NO tells SAS to send a single blank instead of a NULL when inserting rows.  To confirm, log into DB2 with some other app and inspect the DDL on the table.

Comment: Gotta open it up. Found out this solution worked on my character data, but using numeric data, the issue was not solved (neither NULLCHAR = YES nor NULLCHAR=NO worked).

Comment: I added the ODBC tag to your question because I think that's the culprit.  In any case, I very much suggest that you open a track with SAS tech support.  This smells like a bug and they may have a fix.

Comment: I think you might be right about needing to open a ticket. This question is a little too niche for SO.

Comment: You might use OPTIONS MISSING=' ' or OPTIONS MISSING=0 or something like that, and try nullchar=no again - SAS uses '.' for missing by default, and DB2 might object to that.

Comment: No luck with that one, Joe. Changing the null character to something other than a period for numeric data didn't fix the issue. I'm going to give SAS' IT a ring and see if there's an official solution.